# Any way I can get Python sounds to overlap?

Tags: python, audio, pygame

```
import pygame,sys

pygame.init()

size = 40,40
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

LEFT = 1

s = pygame.mixer.Sound("Sound.wav")

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == LEFT:
                s.play()
```

So at the moment, I'm trying to make a game using Pygame. I have it set so a sound plays whenever you click the mouse. It works and all, but I get really annoyed, because I can only hear one sound effect at a time. If I click 7 times very quickly, I might hear only 4-6 sounds. If I click 2 times very quickly, I only hear one sound play.

I've looked on various other questions about overlapping Pygame sounds (it's got something to do with pygame.mixer.Channel, which I don't understand). Nothing has worked for me so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but some one like me might be struggling with the same problem

For CodeSurgeons solution to work I had to initialize the pygame.mixer with a smaller buffer size

```
pygame.mixer.init(buffer=2048)
```

or

```
pygame.mixer.pre_init(buffer=2048)
pygame.init()
```

Comment: I had a similar problem: I repeatedly issued `play()` calls on empty channels returned by `pygame.mixer.find_channel()` at intervals of about 0.25 seconds. The sounds I wanted to play on each of these calls was only about 0.1 seconds long. Anyway the sounds didn't play in intervals of 0.25s all the time. Instead sometimes two sounds came quicker after one another. When I initialized the buffer size to 1024, all was fine, but I had to use the `pre_init()` call to make this become effective.

Answer (score 0):

Playing around a bit, I think that you are right about using `pygame.mixer.Channel`. I would recommend taking a look at the `pygame.mixer` as well as the `pygame.mixer.Channel` pages. The simplest approach I could come up with is to see if there is an empty channel available in pygame (8 channels are available by default, more can be created with `pygame.mixer.set_num_channels()`). If there is an empty one available, then you can use the **channel instead to play the sound rather than the sound object itself**. With those two tweaks, your sample becomes this:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
size = (200, 200)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
LEFT = 1
s = pygame.mixer.Sound("Sound.wav")

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == LEFT:
                print "click"
                empty_channel = pygame.mixer.find_channel()
                empty_channel.play(s)
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: It didn't seem to make any difference when I applied it. I still had the same fewer-sounds-than-clicks issue. I guess I'll keep it for now. Thanks for the response, though.

Comment: @ShawnSong Have you tried using longer test sounds to better hear the overlap? Also, I did find that if I start clicking rapidly immediately when the app initially loads, it does end up missing a sound, so see if anything changes when you rapid-fire-click after waiting a few seconds. Also, it might not hurt to check `pygame.mixer.get_num_channels()` to see if it is indeed 8 by default.

Comment: Could it perhaps be the version I'm using (Python 3.3)? I've seen pygame.mixer.find_channel() work for others online, but for me, it makes no difference. pygame.mixer.get_num_channels() returns 8; I've already tried.

Comment: No matter what sound effect I use, or how long I wait after the program starts up, or how many channels I set Pygame to have with pygame.mixer.set_num_channels(), sounds always seem to have a limit to how fast they can play. If all else fails, I might just remove sounds from my game.

Comment: @ShawnSong I don't think the version makes a difference, since I just tested the code in my solution in python 3.5 and it worked just fine (modifying the print statement, of course!). What platform are you on? I am running my code on Windows 10, 64 bit.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.3 on Windows 8.1, 64 bit.

Comment: @ShawnSong Honestly at this point I am not sure what is wrong. It could be that perhaps SDL_mixer dependency pygame has is not installed, but that is unlikely since the single sound without overlap is playing. Alternatively, you can use other pygame libraries to play your sound. I have seen PyAudio mentioned before, but I haven't personally used it. I am currently using PyAL, which is based on OpenAL and is low level, to play sounds in my 3D engine since it has 3D positional audio, but I think it should work in this use case as well.